# How can I get an element in an array based on value rather than index with Json.NET in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So I get a response string:

```
{
    "travels": [
        {
            "date": "2015-10-15",
            "id": 5
        },
        {
            "date": "2015-10-14",
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Which I feed into `JObject.Parse` to get a JObject `data`. I know that I can do:

```
data.SelectToken("travels(0).date")
```

to select the date of the first element. However I need to be able to select the element by id rather than by index since it won't return the same elements every time. Is this possible?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a typed object?

Comment: If you can get the Json to a collection of typed objects, you can just use Linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a class, deserialize to it and then filter it with LINQ:

```
void Main()
{
    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    var selectedTravel = root.Travels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2);
}

public class Travel
{
    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Travel> Travels { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement @Yuval Itzchakov's answer -- you can do this with LINQ without needing to create a concrete class:

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);

int targetId = 2;

JObject result = data["travels"].Children<JObject>()
                                .FirstOrDefault(jo => (int)jo["id"] == targetId);

if (result != null)
    Console.WriteLine(result["date"]);
else
    Console.WriteLine("No object with id " + targetId + " was found");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kZSVVE